# RNN text classification using keras

Tags: python, python-2.7, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have wrote this RNN text classification system in keras with the tutorials available in the web. it is working fine and show output also. But can some one check my code and tell me whether my implementation is correct or not?

```
# LSTM with dropout for sequence classification 
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.preprocessing import sequence,text
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
import pandas as pd


# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)

#fetching sms spam dataset
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pydata-dc-2016-tutorial/master/sms.tsv'
sms = pd.read_table(url, header=None, names=['label', 'message'])

#binarizing
sms['label_num'] = sms.label.map({'ham':0, 'spam':1})
sms.head()

X = sms.message
y = sms.label_num
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

###################################
tk = text.Tokenizer(nb_words=200, lower=True)
tk.fit_on_texts(X)

x = tk.texts_to_sequences(X)

print len(tk.word_counts)

###################################
max_len = 80
print "max_len ", max_len
print('Pad sequences (samples x time)')

x = sequence.pad_sequences(x, maxlen=max_len)



max_features = 200
model = Sequential()
print('Build model...')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=max_len, dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

model.fit(x, y=y, batch_size=500, nb_epoch=1, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, show_accuracy=True, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belong to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: how to determine max_features, input_length and what is 128?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is good, however, the feature "show_accuracy=True" is deprecated. If you want to monitor the accuracy during training and test, please use it as a metric. Metrics can be custom but some of them like accuracy are preimplemented. Use it like thise :

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

if you define a custum metric :

```
def my_metric(y_pred, y_true):
    ....
    return metric_computed
```

you can use it like this and it will be computed at the same time as the accuracy (and the loss by default) during training :

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy',my_metric])
```

Otherwise the implementation seems good :)